# The number of words formed by permuting the letters L,O,C,K,U,P such that neither 'LOCK' nor 'UP' appears in any such arrangement

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Total number of permutations are $6!$ and there are $4!$ ways where the word $UP$ shows up and $2!$ ways where the word $LOCK$ shows up. Also, there are two arrangements where both of the the words show up(LOCKUP and UPLOCK). So according to me the final answer must be

$6!-4!-2!-2$

Am I wrong in this answer?

Comment: I don't think you're counting ULOCKP as an appearance of LOCK

Comment: Oh yes! I revised my answer to $6!-5!-3!$

Comment: You're missing +2

Comment: There are more than two ways the word LOCK can show up:  (1) LOCKUP, LOCKPU, ULOCKP, PLOCKU, UPLOCK, PULOCK.  Three ways of placing LOCK and two ways of permuting the letters UP in each of those three positioning of LOCK.  $3\cdot 2 = 6=3!$ words in which LOCK shows up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MY ANSWER IS 6! - 5! - 3! +2

THE TOTAL FORMS ARE 6!
THE FORMS THAT "UP" APPEARS ARE 5!
THE FORMS THAT "LOCK" APPEARS ARE 3!
AND THE FORMS BOTH APPEARS IS 2 THEN WE COUNT IT TWICE AND MUST ADD UP IT

Comment: Please don't use all caps ... looks like you're yelling

Answer (score 2):

> The number of words formed by permuting the letters L,O,C,K,U,P such
>   that neither 'LOCK' nor 'UP' appears in any such arrangement

The total number of arrangements with no restriction is $6!$

The number of arrangements where **LOCK** appears is $3!$ because we take lock as one unit. Therefore, we are left with LOCK,U,P

- **LOCK**UP
- **LOCK**PU
- U**LOCK**P
- P**LOCK**U
- UP**LOCK**
- PU**LOCK**

The number of arrangements where up appears would be $5!$ because we Take **UP** as one unit and we are left with four other letters. L, O, C, K, UP

- UPLCOK.. and so on ( **120** arrangements )

The number of arrangements where **LOCK** and **UP** appear is $2!$ by taking **UP** as one unit and **LOCK** as one unit.

- LOCKUP
- UPLOCK

Final answer: $6!-(5!+3!-2!)$

---

You were subtracting everything from each other, so let me explain to you what we need to do exactly.

Using inclusion and exclusion principle... In your case, you will need to use this rule

$|A \cup B| = |A|+|B|-|A \cap B|$

Then the answer would be $|X| - |A \cup B|$ where **X** is the total number of arrangements with no restriction, **A** represents the number of arrangements where **LOCK** appears, and **B** represents the number of arrangements where **UP** appears, then finally $|A \cap B|$ where **LOCK** and **UP** appear together.